Adapting Laplace succession to start from a statistic about a population and approximate that statistic for an individual within that population
Let's say I have observed a poker player have $n$ opportunities to 3bet preflop, and I have observed them 3betting $s$ times during that time. If I want to estimate how often the player 3bets and update it as I observe them over more opportunities, I can estimate that using Laplace's succession:
$$
P(X_{n+1}|X_1 + \ldots + X_n = s) = \frac{s + 1}{n + 2}
$$
This makes the somewhat arbitrary assumption that the player 3bets $1/2$ the time (i.e. the result is $0.5$ when $n = 0$). That initial assumption is pretty bad, and it takes a while for the estimation to become at all useful. Let's say I have a large database which shows that poker players in the population 3bet preflop $7\%$ of opportunities. We can change our initial assumption to $0.07$ fairly easily...
$$
P(X_{n+1}|X_1 + \ldots + X_n = s) = \frac{s + 0.14}{n + 2}
$$
However, this still has the problem that it's overly-sensitive to a small amount of data. If the first time the player has an opportunity to 3bet preflop, they happen to 3bet, that results in:
$$
\frac{1 + 0.14}{1 + 2} = \frac{1.14}{3} = 0.38
$$
So just one sample can cause our probability prediction to jump from $0.07$ to $0.38$, which probably isn't accurate, as this would put the poker player in the top percentile of 3bettors.
I can adjust this by adjusting the initial component to have a proportional but higher impact by multiplying both top and bottom by some factor but that seems arbitrary as well. I have the probability distribution of the population of poker players; is there a smart way to use that to adjust the distribution more realistically?
Note that the goal here is to identify players who are outliers, i.e. if a player has a $P=0.012$ 3bet probability, we mostly want to fold when they 3bet, whereas if the player really does have a $P=0.38$ 3bet probability, we want to call and 4bet often.
